# Unicode characters in VBA Macros in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of students and i want to invert the "Name Surname" format to "Surname Name".

My problem isn't the coding, but it's the UTF-8 support for my language.

I tested the macro with looping through the names and displaying them in a msgBox, but i get  question marks for every name.

Anyone else had problems with UTF-8 in Excel Macros?

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 and Unicode mean different things, so it's hard to understand what you're asking for.

In principle, VBA uses 2-byte unicode (UCS-2) internally. This is not the same as UTF-8 which many external programs expect.

The StrConv() built-in function can convert back and forth.